# SSIS Event Handler sends me message, even when there is no error

Tags: ssis, eventhandler, onerror

I have a SSIS package and set Event Handler (OnError) to send me a message with logs:

"Package: " + @[System::PackageName]  + "\n" +"Start Timet: " + (DT_WSTR, 40) @[System::StartTime] + "\n" +"User Name: " + @[System::UserName] + "\n" +"Machine Name: "+ @[System::MachineName] + "\n" +"Task Name: "  +  @[System::SourceName] + "\n" +@[System::ErrorDescription]

The problem is, it fires and sends me a message for each component, even when they run successfully. I even disabled all components temporarily, but still received emails from it.
I can put all components in one big ForEach component, but as it needs much memory, I don't prefer to do that.

Furthermore, I checked all warning and fixed them as well.
Rebuild the solution.
Disabled / enabled all components.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers continue raising events up the chain unless told otherwise. The "otherwise" setting is a System variable named `Propagate` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-ver16

> Propagate Boolean Indicates whether the event is propagated to a higher level event handler.

> Note: The value of the Propagate variable is disregarded during the validation of the package. If you set Propagate to False in a child package, this does not prevent an event from propagating up to the parent package.

Now, I have done just a *bit* with SSIS and even at this stage, I'd have to say my confidence in suppressing error events is still pretty low---maybe I just had weird use cases with it.

Comment: Thanks for respond, but when you set it in "OnError" it should be raised ONLY when there is an error.